# angular mat-chip-grid - when I type the key right t M (,<) on keyboard it is act as enter

Tags: angular, typescript-typings

my code is similar to:

https://material.angular.io/components/chips/overview
( Chips connected to an input field)

```
<mat-form-field class="example-chip-list">
  <mat-label>Favorite Fruits</mat-label>
  <mat-chip-grid #chipGrid aria-label="Enter fruits">
    <mat-chip-row *ngFor="let fruit of fruits"
                  (removed)="remove(fruit)"
                  [editable]="true"
                  (edited)="edit(fruit, $event)"
                  [aria-description]="'press enter to edit ' + fruit.name">
      {{fruit.name}}
      <button matChipRemove [attr.aria-label]="'remove ' + fruit.name">
        <mat-icon>cancel</mat-icon>
      </button>
    </mat-chip-row>
    <input placeholder="New fruit..."
           [matChipInputFor]="chipGrid"
           [matChipInputSeparatorKeyCodes]="separatorKeysCodes"
           [matChipInputAddOnBlur]="addOnBlur"
           (matChipInputTokenEnd)="add($event)"/>
  </mat-chip-grid>
</mat-form-field>
```

```
add(event: MatChipInputEvent): void {
    const value = (event.value || '').trim();

    // Add our fruit
    if (value) {
      this.fruits.push({name: value});
    }

    // Clear the input value
    event.chipInput!.clear();
  }
```

when I type the key right to m (,<) keyboard - the add event called as it was entered

what do I need to do to fix that problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's likely just because you have COMMA in your set of seperator key codes. In your ts file look for your `separatorKeysCodes` variable and remove COMMA.

For example given the code in the link you provided, update:

```
separatorKeysCodes: number[] = [ENTER, COMMA];
```

to just

```
separatorKeysCodes: number[] = [ENTER];
```